# CustomlistAdapters in android

Tags: android

i need to do pagination for listview.i.e i have static 10 text items.i need to show first 5 items in first page.when user clicks 'next' button remaining 5 text items should be displayed that replaces the old 5.How could i do this?

Corrected code....

```
public class listact extends ListActivity {
    String str1,str2;
    Button next;
    TextView selection;
    String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"};
    String[] items1={"consectetuer","pepsi","coke","mirinda","tion"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);

    final ListView list = getListView();

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);

list.setAdapter(adapter);

 next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(listact.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items1);

                list.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


});


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one.

```
    ListView list = getListView();
    CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(listact.this,items);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v) {
           adapter.notifydatasetchanged();

           CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(listact.this,items1);
           list.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be i dono exactly...but create an array of first 5 items instead of 10.
First time show 5 items in list view..

When next is clicked..
remove first items in array and add  next 5 items in array.

then invalidate the adapter...by calling

> adapter.notifydatasetchanged();

That will work..

Comment: @user304785 Thanks for ur reply..I've changed my code as u said.Will it work?Or let me know the correction pls..

Comment: Nope..i dont think so..because in my java file..where can i send my items1 array to CustomListAdapter?  String[] items1={"consectetuer","pepsi","coke","mirinda","tion"};

Comment: i said create only one array items[] and add first 5items to that..!! when u clicked remove the items in items[] and add next 5 items to same array items[]..after that call adpater.notify.....so it will load next items instead of first..

Comment: Oh...i know ur concept.But i dont know how to do this.Can u have example code or link for this pls?

Answer (score 0):

just try this one...

```
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row,R.id.txtlist,items);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


       next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

    public void onClick(View v) {
       adapter.notifydatasetchanged();


     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row,R.id.txtlist,items1);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


}


  });
```

in row.xml contain only textview